# Найти сумму чисел от -1000 до 1000 которые заканчиваются на +-2, +- 3 и +- 7

Tags: javascript, математика

Я, наверное, неправильно использую `Math.abs`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```js
var start = -1000;
var finish = 1000;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
  if (i % 10 === Math.abs(2) || i % 10 === Math.abs(3) || i % 10 === Math.abs(7)) {
    sum += i;
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет смысла заключать числа в Math.abs(). Заключайте i % 10 в Math.abs() таким образом

```
Math.abs(i % 10) === 2
```

В JavaScript остаток от деления может быть отрицательным числом

Answer (score 2):

Нет смысла брать модуль от положительного числа:

```
Math.abs(2) === 2
```

Также, нужно заметить, что числовой ряд симметричен, каждому положительному числу в этой сумме соответствует равное по модулю отрицательное число.
**Таким образом, в текущей постановке задачи ответом будет 0.**

```
Сумма(-997, -993, -992, ..., 992, 993, 997) = 0
```

---

Можно попробовать сложить модули подходящих чисел:

```js
var start = -1000;
var finish = 1000;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
  var last_digit = Math.abs(i) % 10;
  //if (last_digit === 2 || ...)
  if ([2, 3, 7].indexOf(last_digit) !== -1) sum += Math.abs(i);
}
console.log(sum);
```